# Using network locations with Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, c++

I'm trying to reference a location on a network drive for Windows Visual Studio Code's c++ add-on include path. But VSC cannot find the location.

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Custom",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "\\\\ndev\\somepathtostuff"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "compilerPath": "",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

The path I'm trying to reference is \\ndev\somepathtostuff'.
Is there any reason why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 2):

After posting this, I realized that while using forward slashes for network locations in the file explorer does not work. It does for VSC.

So, the path '\\bin\stuff' becomes '//bin/stuff'.